# AVSpeechSynthesizer stops Working after something like 200 calls

Tags: swift, xcode, avspeechsynthesizer

Im using the AVSpeechSynthesizer in order to speak a text, after using it for somting like 200 times some weird behaviour is happening(in the macOS Simulator, also in the iPad Simulator)
after something like 200 calls(`synthesizer.speak(utterance)`), that everything work as expected , it suddenly get into the `didCancel` method() of he's AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegte, and stops working for good!,not even the `didCancel` ever called again, or any of the other delegate methods are called the `synthesizer.speak(utterance)` just do noting.

I've tried to assigned the synthesizer reference to a new AVSpeechSynthesizer instance inside that `didCancel` method , but it had no effect on it, after the `didCancel` method accrued the only thing that 'make it come back' is running the app again, and then again after using the synthesizer speak method for something like 200 calls, its becoming broken again.
this is my code:

```
   var synthesizer:AVSpeechSynthesizer! = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
       override func viewDidLoad() { 
synthesizer.delegate = self
}

    func speakText(utterance: AVSpeechUtterance ) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
        
        print("speak now \(utterance.speechString)")
    }


  func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didCancel utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
            
        print(" AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate cancel")
      

        }
```

Comment: I had encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

well I manage to fix that issue, I was calling the `speakText(utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)` method from an `if else` statement that was changing the utterance text as needed and then call the function inside each block.(in the `if` and the `else` blocks)

what I did was getting the utterance outside of the blocks, and assign it to nil: `var utterance:AVSpeechUtterance`.
then in the `if else` blocks I've assign it with appropriate value .

then outside of the blocks, I've checked that the value was set, and if it was set(not a nil). all that functionality was warped in a function that was triggered from a synced global thread block . like so

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).sync{ [unowned self] in
            
            self.userDidEnterText(text: text)
            
        }
```

hope this kind of handle may give an idea or direction for someone that will face that problem in the future.